# Assignment in conditional expressions - what are the potential code quality consequences of this?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, conditional-statements

While doing the code inspection of one of the project, I have come across that Resharper is giving "Assignment in conditional expression" warning for a code block similar to below:

```
if (this.pnlSummary.Visible = isValid)
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    // do something
}
```

While I agree that this compromises readability to some extent.. but apart from that I dont think there are any disadvantages of using this as far as code execution is concerned.

Could anyone please suggest what could be the potential consequences of writing assignments in conditional expressions?

Based on that, I will instruct developers to avoid writing such code.

Any advice on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: I would say that you already know what the problem is, *readability*. The expectation is that you're writing a comparison, it's an if-statement after all, but the consequence is that you're also doing an assignment, so something that checks something also becomes something that changes something. It isn't expected, it will definitely lead to longer troubleshooting sessions. Additionally, if a tool built for warning about potentially bad code warns you about some code you should (in general) have a very darn good reason for just telling the tool to shut up, as opposed to actually fixing it.

Comment: Now, once you know what the code does, will this in fact do something else? I mean, now that we know that it in fact does an assignment, and then also acts upon the value of that assignment, will it behave oddly, like taking the wrong branch? No, it won't. Barring some odd compiler bug, this will behave as "expected". I say that in quotes because now we expect it to do an assignment. Basically, you're asking what people *think*, so voting to close this as based on opinions.

Comment: In general you should instruct your developers to avoid writing code that produces warnings. And before you start asking the tool (compiler, visual studio, resharper, etc.) to stop complaining about something, again, you should have a very darn good reason to do so.

Comment: If you, at some point, absolutely unequivocally must write code that some tool complains about, put in a comment, make sure the next programmer that comes along both sees the problem and knows that this is not a problem that should be "fixed".

Comment: Thanks for your responses. But I haven't complained about the tool in any manner in my original question.. when I ask my developers to not to write some kind of code, I should have all possible reasons to explain them what is wrong and why it is a bad practice! And for that, it is important to check with experts in the community and to know what they think. I appreciate your responses and inputs you have provided. thanks

Comment: I didn't say you complained about the tool :) I said you tried to find reasons to ignore what the tool complains about :) I understand now that you're looking for reasons you can go back to your developers with that back the fact that such code (probably) shouldn't be written, but in that respect I still hold my previous standpoint. The developers should have a very good reason for writing it that way, if they don't, then that is enough to not write it like that. I apologize if my previous comments sounded harsh, that was not my intent at all.

Comment: Not really, it didn't sound harsh at all :) think i misinterpreted it :) Yes, you are write, if there is no strong reason to go against the best practice, then the developers should avoid writing such code. I think I have got enough reasons to explain them what's wrong in the code and  why it should be avoid. Thank you very much Lasse :)

Comment: I think the best simple single answer I could give to such a question is that part; don't write code that produces warnings and don't tell the tool that gives you the warning to drop warning you, fix the code instead. At some point a developer might come back and say "this rule is too strict for this instance, you see, because ..." and then he/she probably has a very good reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A good programmer is a programmer who writes code that his coworkers understand not the one who writes code that computers understand.**

> While I agree that this compromises readability to some extent.

There you are. This is absolutely a good reason to prevent programmers from writing code like this.
Also when you can write better code with just few keystrokes then what is the reason behind doing something harmful?

```
this.pnlSummary.Visible = isValid;
if (this.pnlSummary.Visible)
{
    //do something
}
else
{ 
   // do something
}
```

you see? just some keys and few dots. Auto-complete is awesome!

Comment: Personally I would write `if (isValid)` though. I would even consider moving the assignment into the respective branch, to make it a bit clearer that the visibility of the panel depends on whether something is valid or not, presumably there's other pieces of code in the two branches that also depends on whether things are valid or not.

Comment: I think the logic is based on visibility of panel. also isValid and the visibility of panel are coupled together now but maybe in future someone changes the code and removes the line `this.pnlSummary.Visible = isValid;`. and change it to `this.pnlSummary.Visible = isValid2;` and forget to update the if condition and that makes trouble.

Comment: I agree that it is based on the value of the assignment, but only the OP know what the intentions are, the very fact that we might be in a slight disagreement on what is best is here are symptoms of the kind of problem such code exhibits. Again, in my mind, this is a strike against writing such code to begin with, I wholeheartedly agree with the first couple of paragraphs to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it compromises readability but not in a way "I wonder what that code does?", but rather "It's most likely assignment-instead-of-comparison bug, I will spend some time to check it". Static code analysis tools like R# also will always give false-positives on that.